# Ubuntu 18.04 DisplayLink 4K issues

Tags: drivers, 18.04, displaylink

1) When I boot my machine in Ubuntu 18.04, I have issues detecting the mouse and keyboard if they are connected to the DisplayLink box; eventually I'm suddenly logged out and it is detected from that moment on perfectly fine.

2) Another issue I have is that if I unplug the DisplayLink cable from my computer and plug in again, the screens are not detected anymore. *Workaround*: if I previously **unplug the keyboard and mouse**, then the screens are detected back again perfectly.

**Kernel version**: 5.3.0-28-generic.

I've installed the latest version of the **DisplayLink drivers** on my computer as well: displaylink-driver-5.2.14

Have somebody had any of these issues and know how to solve them or workaround them or does he / she have any hint about them?